# 21.1 LAB: Replacement words

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, split

Write a program that finds word differences between two sentences. The input begins with the first sentence and the following input line is the second sentence. Assume that the two sentences have the same number of words.

The program displays word pairs that differ between the two sentences. One pair is displayed per line.

Ex: If the input is:

```
Smaller cars get better gas mileage
Tiny cars get great fuel economy
```

then the output is:

```
Smaller Tiny
better great
gas fuel
mileage economy
```

Hint: Store each input line into a list of strings.

Here is my code:

```
s1 = input() 
s2 = input()

w1 = s1.split() 
w2 = s2.split()  

for i in len(w1):
    if (w1[i] != w2[i]):
        print(w1[i],w2[i])
```

and this is what i got

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 7, in <module>
    for i in len(w1):
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Comment: What would you expect `for i in 6` to do?

Answer (score 0):

put `range()` before len:

```
s1 = input() 
s2 = input()

w1 = s1.split() 
w2 = s2.split()  

for i in range(len(w1)):
    if (w1[i] != w2[i]):
        print(w1[i],w2[i]) 

#output
Smaller cars get better gas mileage
Tiny cars get great fuel economy
Smaller Tiny
better great
gas fuel
mileage economy
```

Answer (score 0):

The error in the code `for i in len(w1):` is that `len(w1)` returns the length of the list `w1`, which is an integer, and `range()` is expected as the argument for the `for` loop.

**Code:**

```
# Hint given: Store each input line into a list of strings. 
s1=list(map(str,input().split(" ")))  #This is how you can store in the list.
s2=list(map(str,input().split(" ")))  

for i in range(len(s1)):   #As given in the question The two sentences have the same number of words. there is no worry of index out of range..!
    if(s1[i] != s2[i]):
        print(s1[i],s2[i])
```

**Output:**

```
Smaller cars get better gas mileage
Tiny cars get great fuel economy
Smaller Tiny
better great
gas fuel
mileage economy
```